# What is the ruling on not liking God?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy

For example, you accept Islam and all of its rulings and teachings, acknowledge that it is the true religion and believes in the Shahadah, and everything, and you would even die for this religion without a second thought. You have no doubts about it. But sometimes you wonder about the state of things, and you end up not liking God so much and questioning His intentions.
You still acknowledge His existence, and that He has all the powers over you, and His power is over everything, but is it in the same category as shirk to say, hey, you believe but you dont like Him very much?

Comment: What is the nature of your dislike? Can you cite a specific gripe that you have against your Lord? This info would be a big help in enabling me to address your  question in a way that would be meaningful to you.

Comment: I do all my ibadah to avoid punishment because I know my future in the hereafter is in his hands after all. I do extra sometimes for cookie points. I know non of my opinions of the world would change that fact, because it's the reality that we all live in anyway. Thinking a certain way would not change the reality, or the strings that binds me to those realities and obligations. But sometimes I think about the world he designed. I am by all means lucky, but the way he puts certain people in certain circumstances i.e. wars for them to play their part ... just makes me go "God, what the heck?"

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about this site and our model. As to your post: I miss a focused question, is it about questioning ALLAH's action see [ask] and  please consider editing it.

Comment: @SunnyHill If you can tell some of the reasons you don't like God, then it would be easier for me to answer.

Answer (score 1):

As‘salaamu alaikum.

Based on the clarification you provided in the comment, I understand that your “dislike” of Allah - and I think “disgruntled” would be a more handsome and accurate word - is based on what you are mistaking as His “Plan and Design” for life on Earth.

In your comment you said, “But sometimes I think about the world He designed. I am by all means, lucky, but the way He puts certain people in certain circumstances, i.e., wars for them to play their part...just makes me go, ‘God, what the heck?‘”

Dear brother, you have given our Lord a bum rap. He is 100% innocent of what you have accused Him of.

We look out at the world and we see a lot of weird, depraved, barbaric, vicious, ruthless, heartless, heartbreaking, sad, depressing, AND EVIL events taking place everyday. You are laboring under the idea that Allah DESIGNED the world to be the way that it is. That is not true, brother.

“Mischief has appeared on land and sea beause of that which the hands of men have earned, that Allah may make them taste the consequences of their deeds, in order that they may turn away from it.” Qur‘an 30:41

“Whatever good that happens to you is from Allah, and whatever bad that happens to you is from your own soul.” Qur‘an 4:79

Allah is Good, His Plan is good, His design is good, what He wants for His creation in general, and mankind in particular, is good. When you talk about Allah IT‘S ALL GOOD!

Allah sent down Revelation to REVEAL His Plan and Design for our life on Earth. He has given us Guidelines that we are meant to live by TO IMPLEMENT HIS PLAN.

But most of mankind reject His Guidance and deviate from His Plan. We have our own plans, agendas, and designs that we are pursuing. We are creating chaos on Earth!

It is we who organize ourselves into gangs, mobs, cartels, and armies, and we who are instigating wars with each other, extorting the weak, committing rapes and murders, and all that other foolishness.

Allah does not like nor approve of that stuff, and He has attached negative consequences to those behaviors. Unfortunately, we are all in this world together, so people suffer from the bad actions of others. THOSE WHO ARE UNJUSTLY SUFFERING ARE SUPPOSED TO STOP THOSE WHO ARE CAUSING THEM TO SUFFER.

“And fear fitnah (widespread foul conduct) WHICH AFFECTS NOT IN PARTICULAR THOSE OF YOU WHO DO WRONG, and know that Allah is strict in punishment.” Qur‘an 8:25

“And if Allah did not check one set of people by means of another, the Earth would be full of mischief.” Qur‘an 2:251

So it‘s not Allah‘s fault that this world is insane and full of evil. That‘s on us. It‘s also on us to fix what‘s wrong, but that‘s another discussion.

Please make tawbah for saying you don‘t like Allah. It was not a good thing for a believer to say. May Allah increase you  in knowledge and understanding.

Ma‘as‘salaam.

Comment: Beautiful answer friend.

Comment: Alhamdulillahi Rabbil-'Aalameen!

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, it is bad that you don’t like your Lord. Because, there is no reason for you to dislike Him. He is The Most Merciful!!! All Forgiving, All Loving etc... how can you dislike Him? He gives you whatever you want.

Only a disbeliever doesn’t like one true God. Know this.

What’s disbelievers’s characteristic’s?

1. Doesn’t believe in one true God.
2. Don’t like his Lord.
3. Commit unforgivable sins such as **black magic** , **witchcraft** and **wizzcraft** and **shirk**

By not liking your Lord, that’s mean you’re against Him. And you have no right to be against your true Lord.

Comment: Please cite your source for the “characteristics of a disbeliever”? I’m only aware of 1 and 3?